# Windows authentication not working in incognito mode

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, windows-authentication, webapi

I have application in .NET core Web API and Angular which is using windows authentication. Its working fine. When the user uses incognito mode the application asks for username and password popup. How can we override that behavior so that it works like without incognito mode.

I tried to add site to trusted zone local intranet and all login user name and password in Login in internet options. Anything I am missing out.

So far tried adding site to trusted and allow username and passwords to in internet options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, browsers will disable SSO when running in Incognito mode. You'll have to setup each of the users' browsers independently:

```
Firefox set:
'network.auth.private-browsing-sso' = true
```

```
Chrome set:
'Enable Ambient Authentication in Incognito mode' to 'Enable' in 'chrome://flags/'
```

```
Edge set:
'#enable-ambient-authentication-in-incognitoEnabled' to 'Enable' in 'edge://flags/'
```

These settings should let you use Windows Authentication correctly.

Comment: Can these flag be set on network group policy level ?

Comment: I'm not positive, but I believe that this can only be done for Edge.